# Converting Mat to PIX to setImage

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract, leptonica

I'm trying to recognize text from a cropped image but I need to pass it from `Mat` to `PIX` because X-Platform coding.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115368/converting-cvmat-for-tesseract), [this](http://hepeng421.blog.163.com/blog/static/11948517201302911311745/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/aUH1cuGCYW8)

And doing the same function passing `Mat` and `PIX` with the same image, results are very very different (with `PIX` it works perfectly, with `Mat` it gets messed).

What am I probably doing bad?

Thanks.

PD: (This is one of the code snippets that I'm using)

```
String imgToString(const char* variables, Mat gray) {
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        String returnString = "Could not initialize tesseract.\n";
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        return returnString;
    }
    api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", variables);

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    api->TesseractRect(gray.data, 1, gray.channels() * gray.size().width, 0, 0, gray.cols, gray.rows);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    return outText;
}

// The one below works fantastic

String imgToString(const char* variables, const char* filename) {
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
        String returnString = "Could not initialize tesseract.\n";
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        return returnString;
    }
    api->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", variables);

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead(filename);
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    return outText;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is seems to be in a gray image. As tesseract's pix.h header says library works on images with 32-bit per pixel depth. Also tesseract weighs colors, so right alignment of them should be done (opencv on default stores colors as BGR, but tesseract wait RGBA). Resume:

```
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>    
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
...
char imagename[] = "testimg.jpg";
cv::Mat _mat = cv::imread(imagename);
cv::cvtColor(_mat, _mat, CV_BGR2RGBA); 
api.SetImage(_mat.data, _mat.cols, _mat.rows, 4, 4*_mat.cols);
char *outtext = api.GetUTF8Text();
...
```