# How to convert IplImage to lept.PIX

Tags: ocr, tesseract, javacv

I develop OCR system based on JavaCV.

I use following libraries for my project:

- https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv
- https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/tesseract

In one case I need to find some part of an image and recognize letters on it.

I store a part of an image in IplImage type.

But for Tesseract I must use PIX format.

How can I convert IplImage to Pix ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8126992/2836621

Comment: Is there a design issue that prevents you from reading the image directly as PIX ?

Comment: @goodbytes, the author of the question has found a hack. https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/224

Answer (score 3):

Posting the hack like solution found by the author of the question. It can also be found [here](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/224).

```
IplImage prepareImg = ...
cvSaveImage("plate.jpg", prepareImg);               
PIX pixImage = pixRead("/plate.jpg");
```

And from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40195440/javacv-conversion-between-iplimage-and-bufferedimage), you can convert IplImage to BufferedImage as follows.

```
public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(IplImage src) {
  OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage iplConverter = new OpenCVFrameConverter.ToIplImage();
  Java2DFrameConverter bimConverter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
  Frame frame = iplConverter.convert(src);
  BufferedImage img = bimConverter. convert(frame);
  BufferedImage result = (BufferedImage)img.getScaledInstance(
      img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), java.awt.Image.SCALE_DEFAULT);  
  img.flush();
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IplImage prepareImg = ...
cvSaveImage("test.jpg", prepareImg);               
PIX pixImage = pixRead("/test.jpg");
```

--- Source : [Same Github issues](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/issues/224)
As mentioned by a comment by rajind ruparathna