# How to use RGB buffer with tesseract?

Tags: c++, image-processing, ocr, tesseract

Basic tesseract example uses

```
auto pixs = pixRead(argv[1]);
```

to read a TIF image.

However, it isn't clear how to use an RGB buffer (not read from a file).

I tried to find out about [Pix](https://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/struct_pix.html) but the documentation isn't very clear.

Later it does

```
tess.SetImage(pixs);
```

maybe there's a way but I couldn't find the documentation.

Comment: [this page](http://tpgit.github.io/Leptonica/bmpio_8c.html) talks about bitmap io. But it says you can't with windows, just linux, for what ever reason. You may have to write your own interface or treat your memory like a mem file on windows.

Comment: @lakeweb thanks, but I don't need to open bmp files, just process the rgb buffer that already exists in memory. Do you know a way?

Answer (score 0):

That documentation is for a very old version of Leptonica. The current version supports reading image from memory buffer. Look for `pixReadMem*` methods.

https://github.com/DanBloomberg/leptonica/blob/master/src/allheaders.h

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create PIX - you can directly set image data to tesseract with [SetImage](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessapi/5.x/a02438.html#aa463622111f3b11d8fca5863709cc699). See e.g. example of putting [OpenCV mat to tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115368/converting-cvmat-for-tesseract).